# Why does everybody mentions Apache/NGINX/Lighttpd... but not YAWS

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, nginx, lighttpd, cherokee

I see a lot of comparisons between Apache, NGINX, Lighttpd, Cherokee ...
but never a comparison with the YAWS webserver written in Erlang.

Maybe there is a reason for this?
Or maybe YAWS deservers more attention...

Comment: This isn't a place to give products "attention", or for advocacy, but rather a place to solve problems. If you want to ask about YAWS because you have a problem then ask away. If you want to see more answers about web serving mention YAWS then answer away.

Comment: Dear Robert Moir, I've no hidden agenda, because I even didn't try YAWS yet! I am interested if someone has made comparisons already, or if there are missing components etc... I also want to mention I found new products thx to serverfault, stackoverflow etc so I hope a post like these can be useful for some.

Answer (score 2):

Because, In all honestly, I've never heard of it. The others (and IIS) are more commenly known and used.